# Seperate the duplicated rows in different dataframes using R

Tags: r

Let us say I have a dataframe `df`

```
df = data.frame(A=c(1,2,1,4,1,2,5,4),B=c(2,3,4,6,2,3,6,6))
```

If I do `df[duplicated(df), ]` All I get is duplicated rows. But I need a global solution which works on every dataframe and results in something like this:

```
> dup1
   A B
 1 1 2 
 5 1 2

> dup2
   A B
 2 2 3
 6 2 3

> dup3
   A B
 4 4 6
 8 4 6

> others
   A B
 3 1 4
 7 5 6
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind each of dup1, dup2, dup3 and others?

Comment: dup1 has first duplicate set of rows, dup2 has the second set and so on..and others are non-duplicates which can be achieved by `other_rows <- df[!(duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)) , ]` as answered by @Ronak Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just do `split` to get a `list` of `data.frames`

```
lst <- split(df, df$A)
```

If we need to separate/join the unique elements of "A"

```
 i1 <- sapply(lst, nrow)==1
 Others <-  do.call(rbind, lst[i1])
```

We use `list2env` to create separate objects in the global environment.

```
 list2env(setNames(lst[!i1], paste0("d", seq_along(lst[!i1]))), 
        envir= .GlobalEnv)
```

The output we get are:

```
Others
#  A B
#3 3 4
#5 5 6
 d1
#  A B
#1 1 2
#5 1 2
 d2
#  A B
#2 2 3
#6 2 3
 d3
#  A B
#4 4 6
#8 4 6
```

#### Update

For the new dataset

```
lst <-  split(df, as.list(df), drop=TRUE)

i1 <- sapply(lst, nrow)==1
Others <-  do.call(rbind,setNames(lst[i1], NULL))

list2env(setNames(lst[!i1], paste0("d", seq_along(lst[!i1]))), 
     envir= .GlobalEnv)

d1
#  A B
#1 1 2
#5 1 2
d2
#  A B
#2 2 3
#6 2 3
d3
#  A B
#4 4 6
#8 4 6

Others
#  A B
#3 1 4
#7 5 6
```

Comment: @PalepuKartheek  It creates objects "d1", "d2", "d3" in the global environment.  It is recommended to keep the datasets in the list itself instead of creating separate objects.  But, in case, you need that, this is one way to go.

Comment: This will not work in the case where `df = data.frame(A=c(1,2,1,4,1,2,5,4),B=c(2,3,4,6,2,3,6,6))`. I need a global solution not restricting to this type of dataframe.

Comment: @PalepuKartheek   What is the expected output for the new data?  It seems to work with the logic used.

Comment: `d1` has 3 rows which shouldn't be the case. The vector (1,4) is also included in the set. Please run your code with the given dataframe `df = data.frame(A=c(1,2,1,4,1,2,5,4),B=c(2,3,4,6,2,3,6,6))` and check `d1`

Comment: @PalepuKartheek It has 3 rows beacuse `1` is repeated 3 times.  If you are looking for duplicates in both columns, `split` by both columns

Comment: I need the duplicates by all columns (not column specific). The example given is a sample but in real I have like 16 columns.

Comment: The row numbers of `Others` is messed up (like - 1.4, 5.6) any reason or any update to correct that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100449/discussion-between-palepu-kartheek-and-akrun).

Comment: @PalepuKartheek YOu can just do `row.names(Others) <- NULL`

Comment: I actually need the rownames. In this case to be (3, 7)

Comment: @PalepuKartheek  Please check the update, it works now

Comment: Can this solution be optimized anymore ? I have like 14 attributes with 50K records which may result in 14 different d's (i.e d1, d2...d14).

Comment: @PalepuKartheek  Actually, it is not needed to create different datasets in the global environment.  YOu can just keep it in the list.  But even if there are n number of datasets, you don't need to change anything in the code as the `paste` step generate the object names based on the `seq_along`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this gets what you want and accounts for duplicates better:

```
tmp <- df[do.call(order, df),]
out <- split(tmp, cumsum(!duplicated(tmp)))
others <- vapply(out, nrow, 1) == 1

c(
  setNames(out[!others],  paste0("dup", seq_len(sum(!others))) ),
  others=list(do.call(rbind, out[others]))
)

#$dup1
#  A B
#1 1 2
#5 1 2
#
#$dup2
#  A B
#2 2 3
#6 2 3
#
#$dup3
#  A B
#4 4 6
#8 4 6
#
#$others
#  A B
#3 3 4
#5 5 6
```

Comment: @thelatermail Can you please make me understand your code ? using comments in the code or in the reply ?

Comment: Very nice, interesting use of `cumsum`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `duplicated` function to find the rows which are duplicated and create a separate group,

```
duplicated_rows <- df[duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE) , ]
other_rows <- df[!(duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)) , ]

duplicated_rows
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#4 4 6
#5 1 2
#6 2 3
#8 4 6

other_rows
#  A B
#3 3 4
#7 5 6
```

To get it in sorted order, you could use the `order` function

```
duplicated_rows[order(duplicated_rows$A), ]

#  A B
#1 1 2
#5 1 2
#2 2 3
#6 2 3
#4 4 6
#8 4 6
```

Further, you can split the rows using the `split` command (as mentioned by @akrun)

```
sorted_rows <- duplicated_rows[order(duplicated_rows$A), ]
split(sorted_rows, sorted_rows$A)

#$`1`
#  A B
#1 1 2
#5 1 2

#$`2`
#  A B
#2 2 3
#6 2 3

#$`4`
#  A B
#4 4 6
#8 4 6
```

Comment: The `other_rows` is fine but, the `duplicated_rows` you have created is a mixture of all the duplicates which I need as different data frames.
`dup1` - first set of duplicates,
`dup2` - second set of duplicates and so on..

Comment: @PalepuKartheek I checked with the data frame you provided, it works! Could you please tell me what is the output that you get?